# Laravel Resource and Resource Collections

Tags: laravel, rest

I'm learning the `Laravel Resource API` and have setup my controller to pass the data to my Resource and my Resource Collection.

This is the list of servers (`index method`) with the `show method` showing the individual server

**Controller**

**Index method**

```
return new DedicatedServerResourceCollection($product->where('parent_id', 1)->with('dedicatedServers')->get());
```

**Show Method**

```
return new DedicatedServerResource(DedicatedServer::findOrfail($id));
```

I need to format my collection and resource differently. How can I get my Resource Collection to loop through each item and format the changes accordingly?

**Resource Collection**

```
return [
    'productTypes' => $this->map(function($data){
    return [
          'id' => $data->id,
          'title' => $data->title,
          'tagline' => $data->tagline,
          'slug' => $data->slug,
          'dedicatedServers' => DedicatedServerResource::collection($this->resource)
           // I need to pass 'dedicatedServers' === $this->dedicated_servers
     ];
    })
  ];
```

**Resource**

```
     return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'productId' => $this->product_id,
            'type' => $this->type,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'config' => [
                'processorLine1' => $this->processor_line_1,
                'processorLine2' => $this->processor_line_2,
                'memory' => $this->memory,
                'storageLine1' => $this->storage_line_1,
                'storageLine2' => $this->storage_line_2,
                'data' => $this->data,
                'benchmark' => [
                    'benchmark' => $this->benchmark,
                    'benchmarkPercentage' => $this->benchmark_percentage
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either "resource file" or "`$this->map(...)`", not both.

**Index Method**

```
return ProductCollection::make(Product::with('dedicatedServers')->get());
```

**ProductCollection**

```
class ProductCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'productTypes' => $this->collection,
        ];
    }
}
```

**ProductResource**

```
class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'tagline' => $this->tagline,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'dedicated_servers' => $this->whenLoaded('dedicatedServers'),
        ];
    }
}
```

**DedicatedServerResource**

```
class DedicatedServerResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'product_id' => $this->product_id,
            'type' => $this->type,
            'processor_line_1' => $this->processor_line_1,
            'processor_line_2' => $this->processor_line_2,
            'memory' => $this->memory,
            'storage_line_1' => $this->storage_line_1,
            'storage_line_2' => $this->storage_line_2,
            'data' => $this->data,
            'benchmark' => $this->benchmark,
            'product' => ProductResource::make($this->whenLoaded('product')),
        ];
    }
}
```

Note: Prefer to use `$this->whenLoaded('dedicatedServers')` instead of `$this->dedicatedServers` to avoid [n+1 problem](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-n1-query-problems).

Comment: I'm not returning a single product though. I'm passing a group of products that i need to loop through. So I need to map or .foreach through them. Once I have done this I then need to attach the DedicatedServerResource as the relation

Comment: @ottz0 If I understand correctly, using `return DedicatedServerResourceCollection::collection(...);` instead of `return new DedicatedServerResourceCollection(...);` in "Index method" will solve your problem. I Updated the answer.

Comment: If I use the ::collection method I get an error - Call to undefined method App\Models\Product::mapInto(). If I use the ::make method I get Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @ottz0 You are right. When I looked at the illuminate library, I noticed that the resource files with the "Collection" suffix in their name act differently (XyzCollection is searching to XyzResource; because of this, file names are important). I created the problem in my local environment and solved it. You can look at the updated answer for the file changes. Also, you can look at the working [git repository](https://github.com/onuruslu/ottz0) that I created.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a different resource class for the `DedicatedServer` model, like `SecondDedicatedServerResource`.